# How to sort a list in order in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

How can I sort a list in order? I have a list of tuples in a list and I need to sort them in order which I want.

```
list1 = [(2,3,4),(3,4,5),(5,3,2)]
```

I need to sort them firstly by the second element of tuple, secondly(if the previous were equal) by the third and thirdly by the first. Is there any built-in function to do it?

Comment: There's a built-in [`sorted` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), yes. Did you look it up? What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I need the "order sort" like what we have in Excel. What will you do, if you want to sort the list in order you need? As an example, sort by the second column, then third column and then first column.

Comment: Did you read the docs on that function? The how-to it links to? What's what I'd do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sorted(iterable,key)`.

```
>>>sorted(list1,key=lambda x: (x[1],x[2],x[0])
#[(5, 3, 2), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```

---

If you don't want to use `lambda` you can use `itemgetter`.

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(list1,key=itemgetter(1,2,0))
#[(5, 3, 2), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```

Comment: Can I use ascending and descending in each element I need? Or I should choose one of them for all.

Comment: @MehdiAmrollahi `lambda x: (x[1],x[2],x[0])` this means they are sorted bases *2nd* if they are equal then *3rd* element is compared is break the tie, if they too are equal then *1st* element is used as tie breaker.